# Opensips - variables and strings

Tags: opensips

Dears,

I use Opensips 2.4

How to use mid_registrar_save("$(rd{ip.resolve})") to mean variable $(rd{ip.resolve}) instead of string "$(rd{ip.resolve})"

Thank you for your help.

[User Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgGt8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the [save()](https://opensips.org/docs/modules/2.4.x/registrar.html#func_save) and [mid_registrar_save()](https://opensips.org/docs/modules/2.4.x/mid_registrar.html#func_mid_registrar_save) functions have always received *static* parameters for the table name parameter, which is why your string does not get expanded -- it's not meant to.  By requiring static strings, the modules are able to initialize their internal data structures on startup *for each domain*, thus being ready to populate it immediately with AoRs and contacts.

If require a *dynamic* number of location tables (domains), then I don't see a solution to the problem.  However, if the number of such tables is finite on your system, you could use a *switch* statement:

```
switch ($(rd{ip.resolve})) {
case "location":
    mid_registrar_save("location");
    break;

case "location_1":
    mid_registrar_save("location_1");
    break;

...
}
```